# Go back with javascript after javaforward (cookiewall)

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm have run into a problem while creating a cookiewall.

I'm using a csm (weebly) which does not allow me to edit the php so im building a cookiewall with java ( I know it’s not perfect but its gonna have to do for now, since im no great coder and I know no other way to do this)

My wall works as following:
A piece of code checks for my ‘’cookieaccepted’’ cookie when loading any of my pages if the cookie isn’t found the user will be redirected to a page (javascript forward) without any cookies or other trackers where the user needs to click a button to accept all cookies to proceed. By clicking the ‘’cookiesaccepted’’ cookie is set and the user is send back to the previous page.

Only my button is not working it’s sending my users back two pages, it’s like it has forgotten the page where the user was forwarded from?? Is there a way to fix this?
This is my button code:

```
<a class="wsite-button wsite-button-large wsite-button-normal" onclick="document.cookie=&quot;CookieAccepted=CookieAkkoord;expires=Wed, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT&quot;" href="javascript: history.back()")">
<span class="wsite-button-inner">Ja, ik accepteer cookies</span>
</a>
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: Is your question just about javascript navigation? Which browser are you testing with? If you want to ask a separate question about cookies, that might help make your question clearer.

Comment: It's about javascript navigation, not the cookie setting if got that working fine. I have tested in both chrome and edge and both are not working.

Comment: I tink i might have found my problem, my forward is window.location.replace and thus there's no history of the previous url. So i tryef location.assign to overcome this issue but still the original url doesn't appear in my browser historie